# Evaluation of Dynamic suppressed by semicolon

Tags: dynamic

`Dynamic` functionally of *Mathematica* it is really very confusing and I tried and spent a lot of time reading and reading but still not figuring it out comfortably.
I am trying to write a function that does an extraction (kind of zoom) of data within desire range.

let us say I have the following data:

```
data1 = Table[
   PDF[NormalDistribution[3.5, .8], i] + 
    PDF[NormalDistribution[6, 1], i], {i, -5, 15, .01}];
noise = RandomReal /@ RandomReal[{-0.2, .2}, Length[data1]];
data2 = data1 + noise;
```

My goal is to write a function that does extraction (zoom) easily.

I have wrote this function, which does the job perfectly.

```
Clear[zoom];
zoom[list_List] := DynamicModule[{pt1 = {100, 0}, pt2 = {300, 0}},
  Row[{LocatorPane[Dynamic@{pt1, pt2}, 
     ListLinePlot[list, ImageSize -> 400, 
      Epilog -> 
       Dynamic@{InfiniteLine[{pt1, pt1 + {0, 1}}], 
         InfiniteLine[{pt2, pt2 + {0, 1}}]}, PlotRange -> All]
     ], Dynamic@
     ListLinePlot[
      zoomlist= 
       If[Length[Dimensions@list] > 1, 
        list[[;; , IntegerPart@pt1[[1]] ;; IntegerPart@pt2[[1]]    ]],
         list[[IntegerPart@pt1[[1]] ;; IntegerPart@pt2[[1]]    ]]], 
      PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400]}]]
```

I can now perform zoom by evaluating:

```
zoom[data2]
```

The problem I am facing is that if I want to put the `Dynamic` object of extracting the data (`zoomlist`) in a separate line, I have to suppress the output using semicolon (otherwise the output will be huge).

If the function is in this shape:

```
    Clear[zoom]; 
zoom[list_List] := DynamicModule[{pt1 = {100, 0}, pt2 = {300, 0}},
  Dynamic[
   zoomlist = 
    If[Length[Dimensions@list] > 1, 
     list[[;; , IntegerPart@pt1[[1]] ;; IntegerPart@pt2[[1]]]], 
     list[[IntegerPart@pt1[[1]] ;; IntegerPart@pt2[[1]]]]]]; 
  Row[{LocatorPane[Dynamic@{pt1, pt2}, 
     ListLinePlot[list, ImageSize -> 400, 
      Epilog -> 
       Dynamic@{InfiniteLine[{pt1, pt1 + {0, 1}}], 
         InfiniteLine[{pt2, pt2 + {0, 1}}]}, PlotRange -> All]], 
    Dynamic@ListLinePlot[zoomlist, PlotRange -> All, 
      ImageSize -> 400]}]]
```

In this case `Dynamic` of `zoomlist` does not work because it is not outputted.

What would be a good solution (workaround) to this issue.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make the `CompoundExpression` `Dynamic`:

```
zoom[list_List] := 
 DynamicModule[{pt1 = {100, 0}, pt2 = {300, 0}}, 
  Dynamic[zoomlist = 
    If[Length[Dimensions@list] > 1, 
     list[[;; , IntegerPart@pt1[[1]] ;; IntegerPart@pt2[[1]]]], 
     list[[IntegerPart@pt1[[1]] ;; IntegerPart@pt2[[1]]]]];
   Row[{LocatorPane[Dynamic@{pt1, pt2}, 
      ListLinePlot[list, ImageSize -> 400, 
       Epilog -> 
        Dynamic@{InfiniteLine[{pt1, pt1 + {0, 1}}], 
          InfiniteLine[{pt2, pt2 + {0, 1}}]}, PlotRange -> All]], 
     Dynamic@ListLinePlot[zoomlist, PlotRange -> All, 
       ImageSize -> 400]}]]]
```

You could also use `DynamicWrapper` with an invisible display as a part of the `Row`:

```
Clear[zoom];
zoom[list_List] := 
 DynamicModule[{pt1 = {100, 0}, pt2 = {300, 0}},
  Row[{DynamicWrapper["", 
     zoomlist = 
       If[Length[Dimensions@list] > 1, 
        list[[;; , IntegerPart@pt1[[1]] ;; IntegerPart@pt2[[1]]]], 
        list[[IntegerPart@pt1[[1]] ;; IntegerPart@pt2[[1]]]]];], 
    LocatorPane[Dynamic@{pt1, pt2}, 
     ListLinePlot[list, ImageSize -> 400, 
      Epilog -> 
       Dynamic@{InfiniteLine[{pt1, pt1 + {0, 1}}], 
         InfiniteLine[{pt2, pt2 + {0, 1}}]}, PlotRange -> All]],
    Dynamic@ListLinePlot[zoomlist, PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400]}]]
```

Or you update `zoomlist` within the `ListLinePlot`:

```
Clear[zoom];
zoom[list_List] := 
 DynamicModule[{pt1 = {100, 0}, pt2 = {300, 0}}, 
  Row[{LocatorPane[Dynamic@{pt1, pt2}, 
     ListLinePlot[list, ImageSize -> 400, 
      Epilog -> 
       Dynamic@{InfiniteLine[{pt1, pt1 + {0, 1}}], 
         InfiniteLine[{pt2, pt2 + {0, 1}}]}, PlotRange -> All]], 
    Dynamic[ListLinePlot[
      zoomlist = 
       If[Length[Dimensions@list] > 1, 
        list[[;; , IntegerPart@pt1[[1]] ;; IntegerPart@pt2[[1]]]], 
        list[[IntegerPart@pt1[[1]] ;; IntegerPart@pt2[[1]]]]], 
      PlotRange -> All, ImageSize -> 400]]}]]
```

Comment: `DynamicWrapper` is the good solution. The first one (`CompoundExpression `) means  reevaluate every thing which could delay the performance for large data. Thanks

Comment: @Algohi Yes, the first one basically behaves similar to a simple `Manipulate` and the possible advantages of using `DynamicModule` are lost.

Comment: @Algohi You might add a `TrackedSymbols` options to `DynamicWrapper`, to ensure best performance within a bigger `DynamicModule`.

Comment: Thanks, but note that `zoomlist` should not be localized. The point is to extract the zoomed data (`zoomlist`) for forward usage.

Comment: What is the point of using `TrackedSymbols`? The whole variable symbols are `pt1` and `pt2`.